# Return request context after requests.post

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have a Server A that makes a POST request to Server B using python's request module (`r = request.post(url=url)`). Server B modifies the request and returns a response with a redirect to a url. I can access the redirected url by doing a `redirect(r.url)` on Server A but I need to pass the modified request context along with it. Is this possible?

Scenario:
Server A is running on python Flask.

```
r = requests.post(url='https://serverb.com/validateToken', data={'token':'abc'})
redirect(r.url)
```

Server B is running on python Django.

```
def validateToken(request):
  # On successful validation
  request.session[key] = mapped_token_to_user_id
  redirect('/successfulToken') # On server B
```

When accessing `/successfulToken`, Server B checks to see if session exists on request object but because of the redirects, the request is naked.

Comment: What is the 'request context' here? Are you using Django or Flask or another web server framework here?

Comment: I edited the question to the scenario I'm facing... I hope this clarifies my question a bit. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense

Comment: You didn't explain this  very well, but at least the Django server code shows that a *cookie* is set. Presumably you want the client using server A to be redirected to the `/successfulToken` URL, and not have Server B access that URL?

Comment: put differently: **why** are you redirecting the client that connects to Server A to Server B?

Comment: The 'request context' here is the cookie that Django passed along with the response, and `r.url` doesn't include the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django server will have set a cookie to identify the client associated with the session:

```
request.session[key] = mapped_token_to_user_id
```

See the [Django session documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/):

> The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies. Cookies contain a session ID [...]

You then redirect the browser connected to Server A to the URL returned from Server B, but you discard the cookie information. The client connecting to Server A doesn't have the cookie, so it won't pass this on to Server B.

And **unless Server B is on the same domain as Server A**, you can't pass that cookie along to the client. Browsers will not send cookies received from one domain to another domain; cookies for *stackoverflow.com* should not be shared with, say, *google.com*, that would be a really big security issue if they did.

So if Server A and Server B are on two different domains (e.g. `foo.bar.example` for server A and `spam.ham.example` for server B) then there is no path for you to pass along the cookie to the client as you redirect the client to server B. In that case you must have Server A **directly** connect to the new Server B URL, passing along the cookie from the response.

If Server A and Server B do share a domain (`foo.bar.example` and `spam.bar.example` share `.bar.example` as the domain name), then you can set a cookie for that shared domain name (with a `.` prefix on the name) to tell the client that it can share this cookie with all servers in the same domain name.

Either way, you need to extract the session cookie; the [default name used by Django is `sessionid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_NAME):

```
session_cookie = r.cookies['sessionid']
```

If you are going to connect to the new URL from server A, you need to add that cookie to the outgoing request (`requests.get(url, cookies={'sessionid': session_cookie}`).

If you are going to give it to the client on a redirect, set it on the response before you return it:

```
response = redirect(r.url)
response.set_cookie('sessionid', session_cookie, domain='.bar.example')
return response
```

Comment: Thank you for illustrating this concept so well. It is definitely because these two servers don't share the same domain so I am unable to see the cookie set... Also, it is unfortunate but I have this setup due to the hoops I had to jump through revolving GAE Standard cons which required a Flex setup.